# Line number not displaying in StackTrace. I can't seem to find the line number an error is happening on

Tags: c#, exception

I have an app that is throwing an exception outside of a try ... catch block. The exception looks like this:

> 2021-01-18 17:11:38.840 -06:00 [ERR] Collection was modified;
> enumeration operation may not execute. 2021-01-18 17:11:38.848 -06:00
> [ERR]    at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
> resource)    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.GetPointsInterval(List`1
> seriesList, Boolean isLogarithmic, Double logarithmicBase, Boolean
> checkSameInterval, Boolean& sameInterval, Series& series)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultFromData(Axis
> axis)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultFromIndexesOrData(Axis
> axis, AxisType axisType)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean
> initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics
> graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs
> e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
> Int16 layer)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I understand that there is a collection being modified while it is being iterated. I can't seem to find where it is. I am debugging remote on a machine on the local network. I have wrapped areas that I suspect the exception is happening with try ... catch blocks but no luck in finding it.

I have also added the following in my Main() to try to catch the error:

```
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

After the main I have the following handlers:

```
    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Log the exception, display it, etc
        Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
        Log.Error("");
        Log.Error(e.Exception.Message);
        Log.Error(e.Exception.StackTrace);
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Log the exception, display it, etc
        Console.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message);
        Log.Error("");
        Log.Error((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message);
        Log.Error((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).StackTrace);
    }
```

How can I get the line numbers of the code throwing the exception? Or really...how can I get the place in my source that is throwing the error?

Comment: Break on exception, then walk the stack back to your code.

Comment: Seems like maybe you need a lock on that container, to prevent modification during enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stack trace I think you're barking up a telephone pole (a very wrong tree) in trying to locate this.  The trace appears to show the crash somewhere deep in the screen repaint logic.  It's trying to iterate a collection and the collection is being modified.

Your error is whatever is trying to modify the collection when it shouldn't be but that doesn't throw an exception.  For this to happen the errant routine must be executing at the same time and thus must be in another thread.  You have something other than the primary thread messing with a UI element and that's not permitted.  Dealing with UI updates from other threads is a mess of Invokes of routines and ensuring you don't stomp on something is a royal pain in the posterior.

Comment: In other words, your chart has a reference to a collection. Only modify that collection within the UI thread, or use some kind of concurrent collection.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I don't believe a concurrent collection saves you from a collection has been changed exception.  Besides, it's probably not under his control anyway.

Comment: This is on the right track. I am adding a data point to two different data series in a MSFT chart object. I am modifying the chart data thus the error. Hmmm... seems I need to control the refresh of the chart to prevent the chart from iterating the data when I am updating.

Comment: @EricSnyder If you're modifying as it's drawing that suggests you're modifying from something other than the primary thread which is itself a problem.  Using threads means a lot of hassles with ensuring you're not reading wrong data because it was changed as you read it.